# Reading a csv file with all the columns combined into one: thousands place comma issue

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to read a csv file that is formatted with all the data from the dataframe in one column using python pandas. Each column's data is separated by commas.

However, there are also commas in the thousands place so if I separate on the comma, it doesn't work right if one of the columns in a row contains a number over 1,000. How do I get rid of the thousands comma?

For example:

```
CustomerID, Month-Date, Column 1, Column 2, Column 3
      1223,   AUG 2017,       10,      100,    1,100    #The last value is 1100 and not 100
      1224,   AUG 2017,       10,        1,        2
      1225,   AUG 2017,    2,110,       10,       13    #the first value is 2100 and not 2
```

Comment: The first row is ambiguous. The value of the first row could be (1223, 'AUG 2017', 10, 100, 1100) or (1223, 'AUG 2017', 10100, 1, 100).

Comment: Typically, a well-formed CSV file disambiguates this case by using quotation marks. Without quotation marks (or some additional rule) your data is unparsable :( You would need to go back to the program that generated this CSV and fix the problem there.

Comment: This is not worth trying to solve in Pandas IMO. Open the csv file, remove all your commas.

Comment: That is a novel format. Send it back for a replacement?

Comment: Yes, I was afraid this was the case, but just checking to make sure I didn’t miss anything. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: @TomBlodget Yes, that is what I had to do in the end.

Answer (score 0):

As @A.Kot suggested, you could read in each row from the `xlsx` file, remove the `,` features, then re-write to a pandas dataframe.  Something like:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath
import xlrd

fname = '_xlsx_path_\\data.xlsx'

# Open the workbook
xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

# Print all values, iterating through rows and columns
num_cols = xl_sheet.ncols   # Number of columns
for row_idx in range(0, xl_sheet.nrows):    # Iterate through rows
    for col_idx in range(0, num_cols):  # Iterate through columns
        cell_obj = xl_sheet.cell(row_idx, col_idx)  # Get cell object by row, col
        if row_idx == 0:
            columns = [c.encode("ascii") for c in cell_obj.value.split(',')]
            print(columns)
            print(' ')
        else:
            data_row = [d.encode("ascii") for d in cell_obj.value.split(',')]
            print(data_row)
            print(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you can count on having a space after every comma between the columns, you can get pandas to skip the commas that have numbers on both sides.

```
pandas.read_csv(..., sep=', ', ...)
#                         ^^         note the space after the comma
```

Comment: I wish I could count on a space after the comma. That would make it easier, but there isn’t any spaces between the commas. Thanks though!

Comment: @pythonsandpandas then your best bet is to go by absolute positions for the columns. Don't know if pandas can do that.

Comment: Indeed, [`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) can parse fixed-width data files. But the nicely aligned data was edited into the question by another user, not the OP, so I'm not sure if this would really help the OP.